# Typescript awaiting multiple subscriptions

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

I have an Observable containing a list of ID's. For each ID, i wish to get the object which the ID represents. Doing this requires me to get an observable for each object. How do I make sure all objects have been received before continuing?

This is a many-to-many relation in a database.

```
getExercises(programKey: string): Observable<Array<Exercise>> {
    let source = Observable.create(observer => {
      // ... stuff here ...
      programExercises.subscribe(programExercisesSnapshot => {
        let exercises = Array<Exercise>();
        programExercisesSnapshot.forEach(programExercise => {
          let exercise = this.getExercise(programExercise.ExerciseKey); // Returns Observable<Exercise>
          exercise.subscribe(exerciseSnapshot => exercises.push(exerciseSnapshot)); // TODO: Need to await all these subscriptions before calling observer.next()
        });
        observer.next(exercises);
      });

      return () => { }; // Dispose
    });

    return source;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apart from the fact that returning Array as a result of Observable looks a bit odd, this is how I'd do it:

```
getExercises(programKey: string): Observable<Array<Exercise>> {
    // ... stuff here ...
    return programExercises
        // assuming that programExercisesSnapshot is an array or can be easily converted to it
        .flatMap(programExercisesSnapshot => Observable
            .from(programExercisesSnapshot)
            .flatMap(programExercise => this.getExercise(programExercise.ExerciseKey))
            .bufferCount(programExercisesSnapshot.length));
```

Now let's see how this is supposed to work. Let's start with inner thing.

1. we generate observable from array `programExercisesSnapshot`, which then emits its elements one by one;
2. we catch those elements and **replace** them in the flow with the results of observables returned by `this.getExercise(programExercise.ExerciseKey)` calls using `flatMap()`;
3. `bufferCount()` gathers `programExercisesSnapshot.length` elements into a single array and emits it as a result.

So, this whole pipeline emits arrays of results of `this.getExercise()` calls.

Now, the outer thing does the following:

1. it takes batches emitted by `programExercises`;
2. replaces them with the results (e.g. arrays) emitted by previously described observable;
3. and emits those results as its own.

Profit! :)

One more thing you missed in your original solution is a cleanup. When you do `programExercises.subscribe()` you also need to unsubscribe from it manually as well. Doing as I suggested eliminates the need of it - rxjs will take care about it for you.

Also, as I told in the beginning, returning an Array in the observable looks a little bit odd. I hope you have good reason for doing that. :) Otherwise you may want to consider converting that into observable emitting elements one by one as well.

**UPDATED.**

Since the author confessed :) that arrays are not needed here is another solution, more simple and elegant:

```
getExercises(programKey: string): Observable<Exercise> {
    // ... stuff here ...
    return programExercises
        // assuming that programExercisesSnapshot is an array or can be easily converted to it
        .flatMap(programExercisesSnapshot => Observable.from(programExercisesSnapshot))
        .flatMap(programExercise => this.getExercise(programExercise.ExerciseKey));
```

Comment: That is beautiful, thank you so much! Rx can seem almost like magic for the uninitiated :)
I have no good reason to return an array in the observable. I really just want to return a list of Exercises. Can you explain why Observable<any[]> is bad?

Comment: @user1202032, I wouldn't say it's exactly bad, it is just not a best practice to create collections of collections, which is essentially what you're doing. You just trying to do the job of an observable with that array. Why not make an Observable do its job instead? :) I'll update the answer.